# How to use ament_lint to validate ROS2 package

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In ROS1 it was very useful to run catkin_lint -W2 to validate the CMake and package.xml. Is there a feature in ament_lint to get this desired behavior? I have tried ament_xmllint but it doesn't provide errors or warnings regarding missing depends in the package.xml. If this feature does exist it will save a lot of time developing ROS2 packages.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/370091/how-to-use-ament_lint-to-validate-ros2-package/) by [Boston Cleek](https://answers.ros.org/users/68502/boston-cleek/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2021-01-22

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The best entry point to understand how to use ament_lint I recommend starting here: http://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/How-To-Guides/Ament-CMake-Documentation.html?highlight=lint#linting

The common linters are documented here: https://github.com/ament/ament_lint/blob/rolling/ament_lint_common/doc/index.rst

Including a link to ament_lint_auto which is recommended to simplify enabling multiple linters:

https://github.com/ament/ament_lint/blob/master/ament_lint_auto/doc/index.rst

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2022-09-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2